# Can I use NGINX as a way to reverse-proxy requests to my Go web server?

Tags: go, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Can I use NGINX as a way to reverse-proxy requests to my Go web server? I wanted to study this but everything I came across is either too complex for me or not what I searched (For information I searched it on Bing) is not what I wanted.

Can you also show how to reverse-proxy requests to my Go server? I will put a basic server below.

The Go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    _"net/http"
    gear "github.com/gogearbox/gearbox"
)

type Todo struct {
    Title string
    Done  bool
}

type TodoPageData struct {
    PageTitle string
    Todos     []Todo
}

func main() {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html"))

    var Gear = gear.New()

    Gear.Get("/", func(ctx gear.Context) {
        data := TodoPageData{
            PageTitle: "My TODO list",
            Todos: []Todo{
                {Title: "Task 1", Done: false},
                {Title: "Task 2", Done: true},
                {Title: "Task 3", Done: true},
            },
        }

        tmpl.Execute(ctx.Context() , data)
    })

  Gear.Start(":7070")
}
```

My layout.html file :

```html
<h1>{{.PageTitle}}</h1>

<ul>

    {{range .Todos}}

        {{if .Done}}

            <li class="done">{{.Title}}</li>

        {{else}}

            <li>{{.Title}}</li>

        {{end}}

    {{end}}

</ul>
```

Comment: You can use nginx to proxy requests to _any_ HTTP server, including one written in Go. The question is why you want to do it. That'll dictate what the nginx config looks like for the most part.

Comment: Yes, nginx can be used as a reverse proxy. What have you tried? Include your configuration. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at **Caddy** as your reverse proxy solution. 100% go, easy configuration, gobs of add-ins that make it easy to configure as a reverse proxy.

- https://caddyserver.com/
- https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy